# Recenter GMap map after show/hide

Tags: google-maps

I have Drupal 7 GMap based map, with many markers. I want to hide the map on windows load, an initialize on click. My problem is: after display map,  she don't remember coordonate of center, and map displayed with te bigger zoom. Please help, how to recenter the map, but keep the markers.
I tried this code in JQuery, but I don't need a new map.

```
function initialize(){
   // create the map
   var myOptions = {
     zoom: 8,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng( 32.8512705331102, -117.08586603100235 ),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
   map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( "gmap-mymap-gmap0" ),myOptions );

 }
```

Comment: Have you seen https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap/issues/1841930?

Comment: Yes, but still not working... Thank You for reply!